# Angular Leaflet - Map does does not render properly

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

No matter which way I try in Angular 7, my Leaflet Map does not load properly. I get a block puzzle with half the screen grey and the other half in random disjointed map blocks (see pic).

Map Block Puzzle:

[image]

**My HTML has been either:**

```
<div 
  leaflet 
  [leafletOptions]="options">
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

**My component is:**

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
...
@Component( {
  styleUrls:  [ "../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" ],
  templateUrl:  "./map.html"
} )
...
export class Map implements OnInit {

  map: any;

  options = {
    layers: [
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 7, attribution: '...' })],
        zoom: 5,
        center: L.latLng([ 46.879966, -121.726909 ])};

  async ngOnInit() {

    this.map =  L.map('map').setView( [37.8, -96], 4 );
    var osmUrl    = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var osm       = new L.TileLayer( osmUrl, { minZoom: 1, maxZoom: 7, attribution: osmAttrib } );      
    this.map.addLayer( osm ); // */

  }

}
```

My app-module.ts has the "LeafletModule.forRoot()" added to the Imports.
invalidateSize() did not work for me, though perhaps I used it wrong. I did it with a setTimeout and not, in a method call.

Am I missing something? Do I have to add a script to INDEX.HTML like this or something?

```
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4/leaflet.js"></script>
```

I have searched a lot of posts and followed tutorials, but nothing gets me a nice map loaded.

Can anyone help?

Thanks, 
Moa

Comment: I had the same problem time ago, just to be sure, once the map is loaded, resizing the browser page make the map load correctly?

Comment: When I resize the browser, the map is still gobbledegook. So invalidateSize() is not the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to follow:

1.install leaflet and import leaflet css style on angular.json

```
"styles": ["../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css", "styles.css"],
```

2.import leaflet in your ts:

`import * as L from "leaflet";`

3.initialize your map inside ngOnInit:

```
map;
ngOnInit() {
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([46.879966, -121.726909], 7);

    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
          attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/o4jz3ww85y)

You do not need to use script & cdns since you import the files directly from the local folder. Plus you were trying to use leaflet 0.4 which is really obsolete version

Comment: Question: My Angular project is with styles of SCSS. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Not at all. You just need to import `leaflet.css` styles on `angular.json` so that the map is rendered as expected. Check the demo. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Ok, I'm quite a few hours away from adding it, but will try to add it to my `angular.json`. But it will look like this for me: `"styles": ["../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css", "styles.scss"],`. Notice that the styles is SCSS. Is that ok?

Comment: `leaflet.css` is the file which comes from leaflet's styles, the library. `styles.scss` is the angular root styles which is configured by the user to be used in the entire angular app. Similarly in components. There is no conflict between the two. If you also use other libraries like for instance `font-awesome` you can import its .css file with no conflict.

Comment: It did work, yes!! But one thing was not mentioned, though perhaps because I'm no expert, it wasn't needed.
When you add the `"./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"` to your `angular.js` RESTART your project! `npm start` was what I was missing. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Moa Thank you so much, `npm start` saved me. I thought I was going crazy over here!

Comment: @Moa thank you. I was going crazy and this was the problem. Thank you very much. Your answer is useful

Answer (score 3):

**I am using Angular Cli: 9.1.1**

Install `leaflet` by `npm` command in the console

```
npm i leaflet
```

Modify ***angular.json*** file like this

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "./src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
            ],
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***And finally Re-Run the project by `ng serve`***

Answer (score 0):

This is due to css encapsulation in Angular.

### Solution : use ViewEncapsulation.None option

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

//...

@Component({
    styleUrls:  [ "../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" ],
    templateUrl:  "./map.html"
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Note! ViewEncapsulation.None will make your component css available to your entire app. Be carful on side effects

By default angular uses the **Emulated** encapsulation.
This applies an attribute to all the DOM elements in your component and adds that attribute to your css rules.
Since the TileLayer (also other elements/markers) are being added manually after initialization of the component, custom styles will not be applied untill you set encapsulation to **ViewEncapsulation.None**.

[See more details of ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)